# c# writing to a file without full path

Tags: c#

If I use this code

```
File.AppendAllText("C:/Users/Michael/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/PuzzleGame/PuzzleGame/PuzzleGameContent/player.TXT", "hi");
```

The file will save and add "hi" to the end of it. However, if I do something like this:

```
File.AppendAllText("player.TXT", "what is good?");
```

The file won't have a "what is good?" at the end of it. I can read files just fine using only the "player.TXT" filename but I can't write to a file using only that. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's the current directory?

Comment: "The file won't have a "hi" at the end of it." are you getting an exception or just not seeing the results?  Are you sure you're looking in the same location that the process is running in?

Comment: I think it not at the same path. I think the player.txt file from the 2nd call is under bin directory

Comment: could you add some more code, showing how you can read the "player.TXT" file -- apparently without the full path?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your working directory is wherever the .exe is (unless you change it).  So you see, when you compile, the exe ends up in the bin folder, so your player.txt would need to be there, not with your source.

**edit**:
I bet you're appending to player.txt THEN you read it and that's why it worked fine, because you created a new one in your bin folder.  Otherwise, read would not have worked.  If you go in your bin folder and delete player.txt, your readfile shouldn't work.

Comment: So the player.txt in the working directory and the source directory can be different?

Comment: your source code is just a text file.  It get's turned into an .exe and that .exe can be copied or moved into any folder on your computer (including your source folder).  When the .exe runs, the working directory is whereever the .exe file is.   So for testing, you should copy the player.txt into your bin folder with the exe. and when you're done, you should copy both the .exe and player.txt into "MyFinishedApp" folder

Comment: The working directory is normally the folder that contains the executable but that can be changed by changing the executable property's or through an API call from the applicataion

Answer (score 3):

Both forms are perfectly valid. The likely scenario is that your second version is simply writing to a file at a different location, because not specifying the path will default to the current directory.

If you don't include a path, you'll want to ensure the current directory is valid for accessing the file.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely there are two files on the file system, one in the directory that is explicitly defined in the first example and one where the executable is running in the second example since no explicit path was defined in the parameter of the method call.

From MSDN:

> Given a string and a file path, this method opens the specified file,
>   appends the string to the end of the file, and then closes the file.
>   The file handle is guaranteed to be closed by this method, even if
>   exceptions are raised.
>
> The method creates the file if it doesn’t exist, but it doesn't create
>   new directories. Therefore, the value of the path parameter must
>   contain existing directories

.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that AppendAllText is a method which will create the file if it doesn't already exist. So when you use an incomplete path it is unsure whether to create a new file in a base directory or add to an already existing file. If you can't use the full path for whatever reason, you could get the current working directory using something like:

```
File.AppendAllText(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "player.TXT", "what is good?");
```

So long as the current directory is correct, it'll work the same as your first working example.